# I want to add opening balance and closing balance per transactions in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want two columns opening (A) and closing (B) i want day 1 closing as another day's opening and closing= amount+ opening

| Opening | Amount | Closing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 52 | 52 |
| 52 | 10 | 62 |
| 62 | 5 | 67 |
| 67 | 10 | 77 |
| 77 | -10 | 67 |
| 67 | 12 | 79 |

Comment: Consider flourishing your question with more detail and proper formatting.